# Bootstrap Multiselect stops working after postback

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, updatepanel, multi-select

We are working with bootstrap multiselect component in asp.net web forms application. It's works fine on first page load, but curiously, stop working after a page postback / update panel updates the content. The appearance is fine, but the behavior isn't.

Comment: Do you have any script or javascript functions to do this?

Comment: @Akash, as per the bootstrap documentation we use below script to enable the multi-select options for list box.                                                                                   `$('[id*=ddlProducts]').multiselect({
        enableFiltering: true,
        filterBehavior: 'text',
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        includeFilterClearBtn: true,
        selectAllText: 'Select All',
        nonSelectedText: 'Select Manufacturers',
        filterPlaceholder: 'Search Manufacturers',
        selectedClass: null
    });`

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in your script section. This happens because the bootstrap control will have to be rebounded at every page load.

```
<script>

         $(document).ready(function () {
          Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoaded)
         });

         function PageLoaded(sender, args) {

             $(".DDLmultiple").multiselect({
                     includeSelectAllOption: true
                 });
         }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your script

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(function () { 
'$('[id*=ddlProducts]').multiselect({ enableFiltering: true, filterBehavior: 'text', includeSelectAllOption: true, includeFilterClearBtn: true, selectAllText: 'Select All', nonSelectedText: 'Select Manufacturers', filterPlaceholder: 'Search Manufacturers', selectedClass: null });
}
```

Comment: @amin I tried this it didnt worked in my case.  `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler); function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) { $('[id*=ddlProducts]').multiselect({ enableFiltering: true, filterBehavior: 'text', includeSelectAllOption: true, includeFilterClearBtn: true, selectAllText: 'Select All', nonSelectedText: 'Select Manufacturers', filterPlaceholder: 'Search Manufacturers', selectedClass: null });}`

Comment: sorry to ask, but this must be in the script tag.

Comment: Hey, sorry, its in <script></script> tags and these tags are after </body> tag.

Comment: put a debugger in the script and check if the its calling the method from the browser.@NJAC. The answer I gave works where you have an update panel. Also check if you have any errors in the javascript.

Comment: Hey thanks @Akash. It worked with above solution there was problem with sequence of scripts in my code.

Comment: Accept the ans to close th  thread and give an upvote if you think I helped you. @NJAC.thanks